# React redux, init API call, build an array, display data

Tags: reactjs, redux, use-effect, redux-toolkit

I am trying to learn React. I am using Toolkit and Redux.

I would like to init a call API and then build an array with the data of the API result.

I am no able to display the return of my component.

Error :

````
react-dom.development.js:18525 The above error occurred in the <Driver> component:

    at Driver (http://localhost:3001/main.74c6116b035845d111e8.hot-update.js:53:63)
    at Provider (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:51965:20)
    at App

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries. ```
````

Code :

```
export const Driver = () => {

  const { driver } = useSelector((state: RootState) => state);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
      // API call to get driver working days in a month
        dispatch(fetchDriverShift());
    }, []);

  const driverShifts: Shift[] = driver(driver.workingDays);

  function driver(workingDays: workingDays[]): Shift[] {
    // Build an array 

    return shifts;
  }
  
  return (
    <div>      
      <div>
        <div>Days</div>
        <div>H.St</div>
        <div>H.End</div>
      </div>
      
      {driverShifts.map(element => 
        <Row key={element.index}>
          <Col>{element.day}</Col>
          <Col>{element.st}</Col>
          <Col>{element.end}</Col>
        </Row>
      )}
  </div>
  )
}
```

What is wrong and what should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

`return shifts;`

looks like `shifts` is not defined.